# View Blob File Content

Tags: php, blob

Using some examples I've found at 'devarticles.com' and 'mistonline' I've put together the script shown below that allows a user to save an image file to a mySQL database, saving the file as a BLOB.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'hostname'; 
$db_user = 'username';
$db_pwd = 'password';

$database = 'databasename';
$table = 'tablename';
// use the same name as SQL table


if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// This function makes usage of
// $_GET, $_POST, etc... variables
// completly safe in SQL queries
function sql_safe($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}

// If user pressed submit in one of the forms
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // cleaning title field
    $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title']));

    if ($title == '') // if title is not set
        $title = '(empty title)';// use (empty title) string

    {
        if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
        {
            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
            // Get image type.
            // We use @ to omit errors

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
            elseif ($imtype == 2)
                $ext="jpeg";
            elseif ($imtype == 1)
                $ext="gif";
            else
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error
            {
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
                // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table}
                                SET ext='$ext', title='$title',
                                    data='$data'");

                $msg = 'Success: image uploaded';
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['title']))      // isset(..title) needed
            $msg = 'Error: file not loaded';// to make sure we've using
                                            // upload form, not form
                                            // for deletion

                if (isset($_POST['del'])) // If used selected some photo to delete
        {                         // in 'uploaded images form';
            $imageid = intval($_POST['del']);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid");
            $msg = 'Photo deleted';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['view'])) // If used selected some photo to delete 
{ // in 'uploaded images form'; 
$imageid = intval($_POST['view']); 
mysql_query("SELECT ext, data FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) 
{ 
$image = $row['myimage']; 
header("Content-type: image/gif"); // or whatever 
print $image; 
exit; 
} 
} 


    }
}
elseif (isset($_GET['show']))
{
    $imageid = intval($_GET['show']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ext, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(imagetime), data
                             FROM {$table}
                            WHERE imageid=$imageid LIMIT 1");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        die('no image');

    list($ext, $imagetime, $data) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $send_304 = false;
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'apache') {
        // if our web server is apache
        // we get check HTTP
        // If-Modified-Since header
        // and do not send image
        // if there is a cached version

        $ar = apache_request_headers();
        if (isset($ar['If-Modified-Since']) && // If-Modified-Since should exists
            ($ar['If-Modified-Since'] != '') && // not empty
            (strtotime($ar['If-Modified-Since']) >= $imagetime)) // and grater than
            $send_304 = true;                                     // imagetime
    }

    if ($send_304)
    {
        // Sending 304 response to browser
        // "Browser, your cached version of image is OK
        // we're not sending anything new to you"
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $ts).' GMT', true, 304);

        exit(); // bye-bye
    }

    // outputing HTTP headers
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
    header("Content-type: image/{$ext}");

    // outputing image
    echo $data;
    exit();
}
?>
<html><head>
<title>Save Photo(s) to Find</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for
                 // outputing message
{
?>
<p style="font-weight: bold;"><?=$msg?>
<br />
</p>
<?php
}
?>
<h1>Save Find images </h1>
<h2>Uploaded Find images:</h2>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">
<!-- This form is used for image deletion -->

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT imageid, imagetime, title FROM {$table} ORDER BY imageid DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty
    echo '<ul><li>No images loaded</li></ul>';
else
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while(list($imageid, $imagetime, $title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        // outputing list
        echo "<li><input type='radio' name='del' title, value='{$imageid}'/>";
        echo "&nbsp;<small>{$title}</small>&nbsp;&nbsp";
        echo "<small>{$imagetime}</small></li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete selected"/>';

    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"View Photo\" onclick=\"location.href='<?=$PHP_SELF?>?show=1'\" />"; 
}
?>

</form>
<h2>Upload new Find image:</h2>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="title"></label>
<label for="photo"></label>
<label for="password"></label>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#111111" width="38%">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" height="22" colspan="2"><p style="margin-left: 10"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#FFFFFF"> Upload a File</font></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB" colspan="2"><p style="margin-left: 10; margin-right: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> <br>
      Please select a file from your local computer to upload to our web server 

      for saving in our database. This file can be of any type you like. Once you 

      have chosen a file, please click on the &quot;Upload this file&quot; button below.&nbsp;

      &nbsp;<br>
      &nbsp;</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="34%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><p style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> File Description:</font></td>
    <td width="66%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="64"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><span style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2">File Location:</font></span></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="34%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><p style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> <br>
              <br>
      &nbsp;</font></td>
    <td width="66%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload This File"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can save, list the files saved and delete the files from the database, but I'm having a problem in that I can't work out how to retrieve and view the image, in fact my 'View Photo' deletes it.

I think that the answer lies within 'Outputting List' section, but I've tried all number of ways of trying the 'View Photo' button to execute the 'View' command.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = '';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = '';
$table = 'images';
// use the same name as SQL table

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// This function makes usage of
// $_GET, $_POST, etc... variables
// completly safe in SQL queries
function sql_safe($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}

// If user pressed submit in one of the forms
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (!isset($_POST["action"]))
    {
        // cleaning title field
        $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title']));

        if ($title == '') // if title is not set
            $title = '(empty title)';// use (empty title) string

        if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
        {
            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
            // Get image type.
            // We use @ to omit errors

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
            elseif ($imtype == 2)
                $ext="jpeg";
            elseif ($imtype == 1)
                $ext="gif";
            else
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error
            {
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
                // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table}
                                SET ext='$ext', title='$title',
                                    data='$data'");

                $msg = 'Success: image uploaded';
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['title']))      // isset(..title) needed
            $msg = 'Error: file not loaded';// to make sure we've using
                                            // upload form, not form
                                            // for deletion

        if (isset($_POST['del'])) // If used selected some photo to delete
        {                         // in 'uploaded images form';
            $imageid = intval($_POST['del']);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid");
            $msg = 'Photo deleted';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['view'])) // If used selected some photo to delete 
        { // in 'uploaded images form'; 
            $imageid = intval($_POST['view']); 
            mysql_query("SELECT ext, data FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid"); 

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) 
            { 
                $image = $row['myimage']; 
                header("Content-type: image/gif"); // or whatever 
                print $image; 
                exit; 
            } 
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        $imageid = intval($_POST['del']);

        if ($_POST["action"] == "view")
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT ext, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(imagetime), data
                                     FROM {$table}
                                    WHERE imageid=$imageid LIMIT 1");

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                die('no image');

            list($ext, $imagetime, $data) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            $send_304 = false;
            if (php_sapi_name() == 'apache') {
                // if our web server is apache
                // we get check HTTP
                // If-Modified-Since header
                // and do not send image
                // if there is a cached version

                $ar = apache_request_headers();
                if (isset($ar['If-Modified-Since']) && // If-Modified-Since should exists
                    ($ar['If-Modified-Since'] != '') && // not empty
                    (strtotime($ar['If-Modified-Since']) >= $imagetime)) // and grater than
                    $send_304 = true;                                     // imagetime
            }

            if ($send_304)
            {
                // Sending 304 response to browser
                // "Browser, your cached version of image is OK
                // we're not sending anything new to you"
                header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $ts).' GMT', true, 304);

                exit(); // bye-bye
            }

            // outputing HTTP headers
            header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
            header("Content-type: image/{$ext}");

            // outputing image
            echo $data;
            exit();
        }
        else if ($_POST["action"] == "delete")
        {
            $imageid = intval($_POST['del']);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid");
            $msg = 'Photo deleted';
        }
    }
}
?>
<html><head>
<title>Save Photo(s) to Find</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for
                 // outputing message
{
?>
<p style="font-weight: bold;"><?=$msg?>
<br />
</p>
<?php
}
?>
<h1>Save Find images </h1>
<h2>Uploaded Find images:</h2>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">
<!-- This form is used for image deletion -->

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT imageid, imagetime, title FROM {$table} ORDER BY imageid DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty
    echo '<ul><li>No images loaded</li></ul>';
else
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while(list($imageid, $imagetime, $title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        // outputing list
        echo "<li><input type='radio' name='del' title, value='{$imageid}' />";
        echo "&nbsp;<small>{$title}</small>&nbsp;&nbsp";
        echo "<small>{$imagetime}</small></li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete selected" onclick="document.getElementById(\'action\').value=\'delete\'" />';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="View Photo" onclick="document.getElementById(\'action\').value=\'view\'" />';
}
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
</form>
<h2>Upload new Find image:</h2>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="title"></label>
<label for="photo"></label>
<label for="password"></label>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#111111" width="38%">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" height="22" colspan="2"><p style="margin-left: 10"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#FFFFFF"> Upload a File</font></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB" colspan="2"><p style="margin-left: 10; margin-right: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> <br>
      Please select a file from your local computer to upload to our web server 

      for saving in our database. This file can be of any type you like. Once you 

      have chosen a file, please click on the &quot;Upload this file&quot; button below.&nbsp;

      &nbsp;<br>
      &nbsp;</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="34%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><p style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> File Description:</font></td>
    <td width="66%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="64"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><span style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2">File Location:</font></span></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="34%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><p style="margin-left: 10"><font face="Verdana" size="2"> <br>
              <br>
      &nbsp;</font></td>
    <td width="66%" bgcolor="#FFE3BB"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload This File"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it works for you!!

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and for the code suggestion. I've replaced what I had, with what you suggested and, although I didn't get any errors, my 'View Photo'button unfortunately still deletes the file. I think that the answer lies within the section that starts : echo "<li><input type='radio' name='del' title, value='{$imageid}'/>"; but I'm not sure how to have both the 'del' and 'view' pieces of script working from the same outputted line. Kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM I do not understood your problem.

Comment: Hi @Marcio, apologies if I've not been that clear. When a photo file has been uploaded, my form shows a'radio' button, the file name and the date and time it was saved. A user then selects the 'radio' button against the file that they are interested in and can either choose to delete it, or view it. As I said, I can get the deletion part to work, but not the viewing of the image. Here is a link to my page.http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/uploadfile3.php

Comment: Many thanks for this. Apologies for asking a really dumb question, but I'm relatively new to this, but could just confirm for me please that I'm replacing this line: echo '<input type="button" value="View Photo"/>'; with the one you provided. Kind regards

Comment: No need to excuse. Yes, replace that line with the one I've provided.

Comment: Hi @Marcio, many thanks for the clarification. I've added the code but I'm coming up against the problem you highlighted above, i.e I'm receiving a '403 Forbidden' error, so i'm just trying to work out where I'm going wrong. Kind regards.

Comment: What `<?=$PHP_SELF?>?show=1` prints on your code ? Try replacing `$PHP_SELF` with the exactly name of your script page.

Comment: Hi @Marcio, many thanks for bearing with me on this. Forgive me for asking, but when you say 'name of the script page', so you mean the filename?. Kind regards

Comment: YES!! hahaha the filename, sorry my english is very bad!!

Comment: It's no problem at all. Unfortunately I've tried this and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: That's strange if your url BEFORE the click is the same that you're redirected. Is the url the same or it changes? I'm saying that cause once you have access before you have to have access after run the script. =s

Comment: I must admit to being a little out of my depth here. I've added the most up to date code to my original post if it helps.Kind regards

Comment: So please provide your table scheme, I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi @marcio, please find my table sturcture below:
-- Table structure for table `images`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `imageid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `ext` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `data` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `imagetime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`imageid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

Many thanks for all your help.
Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Marcio. That's fantastic, it works just fine! Thank you so very much for all your help, trouble and patience. It is greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

Comment: Good, just analize the code to understand what I done. I don't changed so much, just touched some `ifs` hahaha see ya..

Comment: I've already started to look at your fine work! Take care and thanks once again.